# Add connected custom post type to product permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use a custom post type (CPT) instead of the builtin product category, because I cannot add custom fields to the product category with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). In the product there is an ACF-relationship field, which I use to select the corresponding post of the custom post type.

Can I use a hook to change the product permalink now analogous from:

domain.tld/shop/product-category/sample-product

to:

domain.tld/custom-post-type-permalink/sample-product

Example: domain.tld/books/stephen-king/the-green-mile

Comment: you could have search on how to add a custom fields in product category instead of using your own category and trying to mess with wc rewrite rules, there are many guides on how to do it, even using something like CMB2, but if you want to proceed with your setup, look at wordpress rewrite rule.

Comment: @silver The product category is not enough for my requirements. I just did not want to write unnecessary page-long explanations. Analogous to the example with the author and book, the website should focus on the author, while the products/books are only an additional function.